# Setting parameters for the Twilio Client incoming call handler

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Is it possible to set parameters for the Twilio Client handler from the TwiML which initiates the call?

Similar to the way parameters can be set when starting a call by using: `Twilio.Device.connect(params)` and then later be accessed in the `Twilio.Device.disconnect` handlers `conn.message`, but in my case I need to set the parameters in the TwiML which initiates the Twilio Client call and be able to retrieve them in the `Twilio.Device.incoming` handler.

Comment: Hi Răzvan, I'm not sure what you mean here exactly. Could you edit the question and add some code that you've tried or your expected actions and outcome, please.

Comment: @philnash: Hi philnash. I'm trying to achieve the following: when an incoming call sends a TwiML request to the server, in the TwiML response towards Twilio set some parameters which could be read in the receiving Twilio Client `Twilio.Device.incoming` handler.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is currently possible, though I'm sure there is a workaround somewhere. For reference, there are [parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection#parameters) on the `connection` object that you receive in the `incoming` handler.